# Extract HTML tag data with sed

Tags: html, sed, tags

I wish to extract data between known HTML tags. For example:

```
Hello, <i>I<i> am <i>very</i> glad to meet you.
```

Should become:

```
'I

very'
```

So I have found something that works to *nearly* do this. Unfortunately, it only extracts the last entry.

```bash
sed -n -e 's/.*<i>\(.*\)<\/i>.*/\1/p'
```

Now I can append any end tag `</i>` with a newline character and this works fine. But is there a way to do it with just one sed command?

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
sed -n 's|[^<]*<i>\([^<]*\)</i>[^<]*|\1\n|gp'
```

And your example is missing a "/":

```
Hello, <i>I</i> am <i>very</i> glad to meet you.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -vFS="<.[^>]*>" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)print $i}' file
I
very
```